# Does the MySQL Connector/J JDBC driver support the Windows Native Authentication plugin?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I'd like to authenticate users connecting to a MySQL database with their Windows credentials rather then maintaining a separate database password for each user account.

The commercial version of MySQL supports this via the [Windows Native Authentication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/windows-authentication-plugin.html) plugin... however it is not clear from the documentation if this form of authentication is supported by the Connector/J JDBC driver.

Experiment suggests that the Windows Native Authentication plugin is not supported by Connector/J... can anyone confirm this, or better still demonstrate that it does work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented under [Restrictions on Pluggable Authentication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/pluggable-authentication-restrictions.html):

> The term “native authentication” used here refers to authentication against passwords stored in the **`Password`** column of the **`mysql.user`** table.
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> #### General Pluggable Authentication Restrictions
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> - ***Connector/J***: Clients that use this connector can connect to the server only through accounts that use native authentication.

Note that the documentation goes on to point out that ***Connector/ODBC*** can use Windows authentication, so perhaps you can use a JDBC-ODBC bridge?

Comment: I think the documentation is pretty clear - thanks for the pointer! Your suggestion of using the JDBC-ODBC bridge is very interesting. I don't need to pursue this on my project, but it would be interesting to see if anyone can get this approach to work!